# How to consume from AMQP queue in browsing mode with Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, amqp

Is there something like "browse" option (see section [2.4.3.3. browse](http://qpid.apache.org/books/0.14/Programming-In-Apache-Qpid/html/ch02s04.html) for details) for amqp endpoint?

Comment: It should work like the JMS browse.

Comment: @Petter Thanks for answer Petter, do you mean using something like from("amqp:myQueue").to("browse:dummy").to("bean:processWithoutRemovingFromMyQue‌​ue") ?

Comment: You should find options here: http://camel.apache.org/browse
That is the camel browse feature, so it won't really work like you expect. The message will get deleted. I'm updating my answer to cover your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out it eventually, I just thought that the option should be there on camel component options level, i.e. after connection string in form of e.g. "?mode=browse", but the option is actually to be set on amqp connection level - "my-queue; {mode: browse}". You can set camel component options adding "?option=value".

P.S. Setting the option on amqp connection level works for even-driven (default camel) routing, it does not work however for polling-driven one, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6784 for details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "browse" component. `to("browse:dummy")`, but that will only make it possible to browse through messages that has passed this route. Handy in some cases, but not really as the JMS browse option.

What you can do is to use a `BrowsableEndpoint` to do a JMS browse (should work with AMQP as well, as it's based on a JMS client, haven't tried though).

You can't really receive a message and not delete it though, so you would need something else to trigger your browsing. Such as a timer or a trigger queue.

```
from("amqp:queue:trigger")
        .process(new Processor(){
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                    BrowsableEndpoint browse = arg0.getContext().getEndpoint("amqp:queue:archive", BrowsableEndpoint.class);
                    List<Exchange> exchanges = browse.getExchanges();
                    System.out.println("Browsing queue: "+ browse.getEndpointUri() + " size: " + exchanges.size());
                    for (Exchange exchange : exchanges) {
                        String payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                        String msgId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSMessageID", String.class);
                        System.out.println(msgId + "=" +payload);
                    }
               }
        });
```

You could do a pre-route to achive this trigger.

```
from("amqp:queue:processQueue")
   .to("amqp:queue:archive")
   .transform().constant("trigger msg")
   .to("amqp:queue:trigger");
```

Comment: Thanks for details Petter, although I was aware of the Browsable Endpoint you mentioned and of the fact that it does not work as "browse" mode.

So you are saying that for AMQP Component there are no options similar to "delete" or "noop" for File Component? That would be really strange :-)

Comment: Why would that be strange? A queue is something totally different than a file. Read the jms docs http://camel.apache.org/jms.html as amqp is the same in camel. You could perhaps make the route transactional and roll back the message in the end of the route...

Comment: Because Camel AMQP Component which "supports the AMQP protocol using the Client API of the Qpid project" would not implement one of pretty basic Client APIs.

And how the queue with messages and folder with files is different for camel regarding read-only browsing?

Thanks for the hint about making route transactional, so you mean that using http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html for AMQP Component Enpoint camel would put the read messages back to the queues in case of roll back? In my case one would need to roll back basically all messages in all routes :-)

Comment: Hi Petter, please see my answer below if you are still interested in the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In AMQP 0-10 there is an acquire mode option on message.subscribe which if set tonot-acquired results in a browsing subscription.In AMQP 1.0 the same is achieved by specifying a distribution mode of 'copy' for the source when establishing a subscriber link.

However, assuming you are accessing AMQP via a JMS client then as Petter says above, you should be able to use the browsing facility as defined by JMS I would imagine (I'm not familiar enough with camel to know how that is done).